# Pandas tests fail with "No module named discovery"

Tags: python, google-analytics, pandas

I am attempting to contribute some code to the Pandas project. When I run nosetests on my test file I get this error:

```
import apiclient.discovery as gapi
ImportError: No module named discovery
```

The code in my test is this:

```
import unittest
from pandas.io.ga import GAnalytics

class TestGoogleSegments(unittest.TestCase):
def test_v3_segment_query_creation(self):
    GAnalytics.format_query()
    assert False
```

I also see that running nosetests on the other tests in the io module results in many skipped tests. I'm assuming that's caused by this same issue.

I get the same issue trying to run this in iPython.

How can I get this running?

Answer (score 3):

you are picking up an older google API library

try deleting all the google API installations manually (you may need to be root for this)

then reinstall apiclient

Comment: Thank you! How do I find the old installations?

Comment: if you are on linux, something like: ``/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/``